# Size of Linux VM XL local disk space

Tags: linux, virtual-machine, disk-space, storage

I want to create a Linux VM server but I don't know what is the default disk size when you create the new server.

Answer (score 0):

That depends on the components you need.  I have used minimal installations at around 2GB with SSH + LAMP... I usually have at least 10GB for a Java project.  More if it's also a development environment.

What tools do you need, and how big are they?  How much code / data are you working with?